# Is it possible to track custom metrics on interaction events instead of on pageview?

Tags: google-analytics

I would like to create the custom metric "rating" and send it on a click event along with a rating value. What am I doing wrong?:

```
var ratingValue = '5';
ga('send', 'event', 'button', 'click', 'rating', {
  'nonInteraction': 1,
  'page': window.location.href,
  'rating': ratingValue
});
```

Reference to docs: 
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events

Answer (score 3):

You need to do two things:

1. In Google Analytics, create a new Custom Metric (admin > custom definitions > custom metrics).
2. In your event, specify the metric you are sending to rather than the name of the metric:

   ```
   var ratingValue = '5';
   ga('send', 'event', 'button', 'click', 'rating', {
        'nonInteraction': 1,
        'page': window.location.href,
        'metric1': ratingValue
   });
   ```

Comment: Thanks for this.  One more follow-up question... how would you suggest I view this in GA?  I created a dashboard widget and did "show the following metric" but am not getting updates.  Also, given that the rating is an int 1->5, I'm not sure the graph visualization will give me the detail I want.  Is there a way to see it alongside content urls or something?

Comment: My preferred method for viewing custom metrics is by creating a custom report. You can do this under "Customization" at the top of Google Analytics.